# mod_rewrite to match 1st and last path segment and replace the last

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rule for my .htaccess file that checks for a match on the 1st path segment, checks that the last segment !=en, and then replaces the last segment.

e.g.

convert

/zh/something/somethingelse/de/

into

/zh/something/somethingelse/en/

If the last segment is already /en/ the rule doesn't need to be applied.
There can be more or less path segments in between the first and last.

I'm trying this at the moment

```
RewriteRule /zh.*/([^/]+)/(?!^en$).*$ /zh/$1/en/   [R=301,L]
```

but it is giving me

/zh/en/en/

as the result

Comment: Isn't it already too greedy due to the `.*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change the regex and add the condition to prevent looping on `/en/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en/?$
RewriteRule ^/zh[^\/]*/(.*)/[a-z]{2}/?$ /zh/$1/en/ [R=301,L]
```

Note: if this is being used in an .htaccess file and you're using apache 2.0+, you need to remove the leading slash from `^/zh` to `^zh`.

Comment: that works! thanks so much - was trying for so long to work it out on my own but with no luck - i'm so grateful to have a solution finally!  now I just need to study it closely to try and understand the logic of it.